# Sending ALT-S to a window

Tags: delphi, keyboard-events

I'm trying to send a ALT-S to a dialog prompt for saving a file using PostMessage :

```
PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_MENU, 0);
PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, ord('S'), 0);
PostMessage(h, WM_KEYUP, ord('S'), 0);
PostMessage(h, WM_KEYUP, VK_MENU, 0);
```

But it does not work. It sends the two keys, but it's as if the ALT condition is not recognised by the dialog box, and handled as a normal S character.

I've done a LOT of reading, including [this](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/windows/simulate_the_pressing_of_keyboard_keys.html) (which produces an error), it seems I need to do something in the lparam to indicate ALT is depressed. Some sources say 0x20000000 but this does not work either.

SendInput, keybd_event, etc will not work for me, since the dialog box will not be in focus.

I'm quite stumped would appreciate some insight.

Comment: What if the user is not running the version or language edition of the OS that you do? How do you know that the label is actually called `&Save`?

Comment: Thanks, but that is not a factor. It's a VERY specialised app for a specific client.

Comment: Faking keyboard input is the hard way to do this. It would be far easier to simply send a `WM_COMMAND` message to the button window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks but I don't think there is an equivalent WM_COMMAND, I've burned some time trying. It's a dialog box with 3 buttons.

Comment: @HeinduPlessis How could `WM_COMMAND` not work? It's how buttons work! Anyway, it seems as though you are dead set on doing it by faking input, so I'll leave you to that.

Comment: It might work if you can get into the process (hook, DLL) and call [`SetKeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646314.aspx).

Comment: Try sending a `BM_CLICK` to the 'save' button if you can get a handle to it. It might fail though if the dialog is not active, refer to the documentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry I'm not dead set on anything, I think I'm misunderstanding how WM_COMMAND works. If you could explain how I can get the correct details to issue the WM_COMMAND I would be greatful.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thanks - though how do I find the handle to the button of another app?

Comment: You've already got the handle to the top-level window I presume since you have to have that to call `PostMessage`. Use `EnumChildWindows` to find the button.

Comment: @Hein - In addtion to David's comment, if the controls of the dialog have identifiers, you can also use `GetDlgItem`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I used EnumChildWindows and have the ID of the button I need to click - I've searched quite a bit but can't find the correct command to send the actual click command. This does not seem to work - SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_MYBUTTON, 0); (where ID_MYBUTTON is the ID of the button received from EnumChildWindows. Thanks for your help so far, I'm almost there..

Comment: It depends on exactly how the app is implemented. If the top-level window is an old style dialog then you would send the message to that top level window. So the window handle is that of the top level window. The message is `WM_COMMAND`. `wParam` is the notification code, `BN_CLICKED`. And `lParam` is the control ID. I'd be using Spy++ to double check exactly how this window is implemented.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you very much - If you post an answer I can accept? My rate is really low..

Comment: @Hein Done. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the easiest way to press a button on another form is to send a `WM_COMMAND` message rather than faking input. Faking input is a tricky business and can often fail to do what you desire.

Send the `WM_COMMAND` to the top level window. Pass notification code `BN_CLICKED` as `wParam` and the buttons ID as `lParam`.

You can use `FindWindow` or `EnumWindows` to obtain the handle of the top-level window. A program like Spy++ would enable you to find out the ID of the target button.

Comment: Thanks David, though I'm sure this is the way to go, I'm not getting any results sending BN_CLICKED to the button id and the handle of the topmost window. By "top-level" window - do you mean the main form? IE not the dialog box that spawned the dialog box of which button I'm interested in, but the main form of the exe? I've confirmed the correct id using both your suggested methods (UI SPy (damn hard to come by)) and EnumWindows.

Comment: Some dialogs are implemented differently, but a standard Win32/MFC type dialog will expect the `WM_COMMAND` to be sent to the parent control of the button. You can find which is the parent in Spy. One trick is to monitor messages in Spy and then click on the button yourself. See what messages are sent where and that can help you debug how to press this dratted button!

Comment: Hi David thanks for your help so long. I've taken this up again, still no luck. I can't find Spy++ as a separate download, I'm using UISpy and can see the ID of the button. Example, if I go File, Save As in notpad, I get the Save As dialog. There's a button on there, ID=1. If I send WM_COMMAND,BN_CLICKED to it, nothing happens. It's direct parent is notepad. Nothing happens if I send it to the notepad window either. However, If I write my own app with a button, it works a charm! What's so special about windows' GUIs??

Comment: The direct parent of buttons on the save dialog is not the main Notepad window. It must be a control on that dialog.

Comment: I can't find that control. According to UISpy the parent of the save button is the Save As form, ID=0. It's ignoring my inputs. Looks like I'll gave to resort to mouse clicks.

Comment: Would you mind my asking why you are trying to fake input to Notepad. I suspect there may be a much easier and cleaner solution to your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
PostMessage(h, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_MENU, 0);
PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, ord('S'), 0);
PostMessage(h, WM_KEYUP, ord('S'), 0);
PostMessage(h, WM_SYSKEYUP, VK_MENU, 0);
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the "Previous key state" and "Transition state" bits of the `LPARAM` parameter both to 1 for the KEYUP messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I can't figure out which bit it is in the LPARAM word. Can you perhaps point me to a resource?

Comment: The [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281.aspx) and [WM_SYSKEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646287.aspx) documentation tell you what the bits are, eg: `PostMessage(h, WM_KEYUP, ord('S'), $C0000000)` and `PostMessage(h, WM_SYSKEYUP, VK_MENU, $C0000000)`.